# Issue running a basic phpUnit Database Test Case

Tags: php, database, unit-testing, phpunit

I am new to PHP and trying to write a basic test case that verifies a connection to a database. Clearly I'm missing something fundamental. I understand from reading the manual online that this involves extending the PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase and implementing a couple of functions (getConnection() and getDataSet()). Please see my code below of the simplest case I could come up with to still get the head-scratching issue I'm encountering:

```
<?php
abstract class DBTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function getDataSet()
    {

        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see, the tests do nothing but return true. However, when I do a "phpUnit DBTest" I get the following message back:

```
PHPUnit 4.2.6 by Sebastian Bergmann.

F

Time: 1 ms, Memory: 7.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) Warning
No tests found in class "DBTest".

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Failures: 1.
```

What am I missing? Any advice would help. Thanks.

Comment: Not seeing any php code.

Answer (score 1):

PHPUnit complains about not finding any test. You must add at least a test method:

```
<?php
abstract class DBTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function getDataSet()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function testDummy()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, phpUnit will only recognize the test method as a test method if it is prefixed with the word "test" as shown by gontrollez's answer.